# Select multiple div IDs using a single css selector

Tags: jquery, css

I have few dives that are identical but they have different div IDs. Is there any way to apply a CSS style to all the div IDs using some sort of a selector, that is cross browser compatible? My HTML looks like this

```
<div id="field_0_dd"></div>
<div id="field_1_dd"></div>
<div id="field_2_dd"></div>
<div id="field_3_dd"></div>
<div id="field_4_dd"></div>
<div id="field_5_dd"></div>
```

Thanks heaps :)

Comment: Give those divs a common class, that's what they're for.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use attribute selectors (`^=` is the *starts with* selector and `$=` is the *ends with* selector):

```
$('div[id^="field_"][id$="_dd"]')
```

Although having this many unique IDs is pretty hard to manage. Give them a class as well.

Comment: I've always wondered, are there any implications to using `"` in your string other than the extra character space? I mean...in some server side languages it escapes the interpreter. Just curious, figured you'd know

Comment: @Ohgodwhy: Honestly, I have no idea. I just put them it because it looks cool. And from what I remember, the jQuery docs always throw them in the examples, so I figure it's the "proper" way to do it. I'll look at the source code right now.

Comment: @Ohgodwhy: Looks like jQuery expects quotes: https://github.com/jquery/sizzle/blob/master/sizzle.js#L1651

Comment: @Ohgodwhy: No problem, I was curious myself.

Answer (score 3):

If you're looking for a CSS selector to match a regular expression, then I don't think you can get it in a cross-browser compatible way (though [CSS2 Attribute Selectors with Regex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49368/css2-attribute-selectors-with-regex) allows you to select, e.g. everything *beginning* with `field_`. Not supported by IE<=6, but there you go).

However, jQuery has the filter function, which can be used to accomplish this easily:

```
$('div')
    .filter(function() {
        return this.id.match(/field_\d+dd/);
    })
    .html("Matched!")
;
```

Answer (score 2):

Just give them all the same class!

```
<div class="common-class" id="field_0_dd"></div>
<div class="common-class" id="field_1_dd"></div>
<div class="common-class" id="field_2_dd"></div>
<div class="common-class" id="field_3_dd"></div>
<div class="common-class" id="field_4_dd"></div>
<div class="common-class" id="field_5_dd"></div>


.common-class{background:green;margin:auto;etc}
```

Answer (score 1):

Could do

- do this: http://jsfiddle.net/uznDG/ **or**
- add a class** http://jsfiddle.net/JH4QQ/
- CHain them: http://jsfiddle.net/ZXBQM/

or few other down below.

Hope it fits the cause `:)`

**code**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   $('div').css('color','green');

});
```

Answer (score 1):

[The starts with selector.](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/)

```
$('div[id^=field_]')
```

Answer (score 1):

add a `class` and then select that.

e.g. `class = "dummy"`

and in the jquery

`$('.dummy')` ... whatever you want, e.g. `$('.dummy').css('color','red')`

Answer (score 1):

```
$('div[id^="field"]').addClass('styleyouwant');
```

And in your css

```
.styleyouwant{

/**styles here**/
}
```