# CSS Increment through id

Tags: javascript, css, styles, dynamically-generated

I have a set of textboxes generated by javascript. some of those textboxes need additional CSS styling. i cannot use the id property because only some textboxes need this styling. i also cannot use the class property because it is the same in all the textboxes.

I am currently using CSS like this:

```
#txtSys8
{
position: relative;
left: 203px;
}

#txtSys9
{
position: relative;
left: 203px;
}

#txtSys10
{
position: relative;
left: 203px;
}
```

is there a way in which i can loop through these ids (from #txtSysy8 to #txtSys19) without setting the styles separately?

This is the code to generate the html

```
rssTag ="<TABLE id='rssTable' border=\"0\" width=\"100%\"><TBODY>";

for(var i=8; i<arrGridData.length; i++){

var upToNCharacters = arrGridData[i][0].substring(0, 13);

if(upToNCharacters == "RSS_FEED_LINK"){
rssTag+="<TR><TD><font>" + arrGridData[i][1] + ":</TD><TD>  <input type=\"text\" id=\"txtSys"+i+"\" name=\"txtSys"+i+"\" onChange=\"pgEdited()\" tabindex=\" " +(i+1) +"\" class=\"fontDefault\"></TD><TD><input type=\"checkbox\" id=\"check" + arrGridData[i][0].substring(14, arrGridData[i][0].toString().length) + "\" name=\"check\" onChange=\"pgEdited()\" class=\"chk\"/></TD></TR>";

        }else{
rssTag+="<TR><TD><font>" + arrGridData[i][1] + ":</TD><TD><input type=\"text\" id=\"txtSys"+i+"\" name=\"txtSys"+i+"\" onChange=\"pgEdited()\" tabindex=\" " +(i+1) +"\" class=\"fontDefault\"></TD></TR>";

        }
        createArrControls(i);

rssTag += "</TBODY></TABLE>";

document.getElementById('tableDiv2').innerHTML=rssTag;
```

I am checking a javascript array and if the array holds a string with "RSS_FEED_LINK", it will append a textbox and a checkbox to the string "rssTag". else, only a textbox will be added.

*I need to add the styles to these generated textboxes*

Comment: Is there any reason you can't give those elements a class? Please show us your HTML so that we can give a more accurate answer.

Comment: You can have multiple classes on one element.

Comment: So which elements need what properties? What does your HTML look like?

Comment: Also you can use commas in CSS to define multiple selectors for the same rules

Comment: [**LESS**](http://lesscss.org/) is a language that compiles to CSS and lets you do exactly that sort of things easily and keep it DRY

Comment: I edited the post and added the javascript. How can I add the multiple classes thing here? i tried adding but it didn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

change the texboxes which need new styles from

```
<input type='textbox' id="txtId" class="someClass"/> 
 to
<input type='textbox' id="txtId" class="someClass myClass">

 .myClass
{
 /*add your styles here*/
}
```

to add extra classes using pure JavaScript

```
document.getElementById("myDiv").className += " myClass";
```

Comment: +1 Multiple classes seem like the better approach here. OP you should consider giving that class a semantic name too, what is the common denominator of all those DIVs?

Comment: Thanks. I tried adding mutiple classes, but it didn't work. please check the javascript code i added to the question.

Answer (score 5):

You can use
[sub string matching attribute selector](http://blog.teamtreehouse.com/css3-substring-matching-attribute-selectors)

The `[attribute^=value]` selector matches every element whose attribute value begins with a specified value.

```
div[id^='txtSys'] {
   position: relative;
   left: 203px;
}
```

Comment: good answer. for more informations about the selector type for regex: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/49368/css2-attribute-selectors-with-regex

Comment: It's a substring matching attribute selector not a regex selector. You can not pass a regular expression to it, it just checks the prefix.

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum you are right. but for any reasons many peopele i know call it a regex selector :/

Comment: @Benjamin Gruenbaum : you're totally right. According the spec http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#selectors , it will be hard to do  better in css, javascript will surely be more appropriate.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks all... It works fine now

My javascript:

```
rssTag+="<TR><TD><font>" + arrGridData[i][1] + ":</TD><TD><input type=\"text\" id=\"txtSys"+i+"\" name=\"txtSys"+i+"\" onChange=\"pgEdited()\" tabindex=\" " +(i+1) +"\" class=\"fontDefault textClass\"></TD></TR>";
```

I added another class to the textbox (class=\"fontDefault textClass\").

My CSS:

```
input.textClass
{
position: relative;
left: 202px;
}
```