# How to select a tag by just its first characters?

Tags: javascript

Lets assume this will be the tag:

```
<iframe name="tag_name_43502" ........ > ... </iframe>
```

`43502` is a random number.It get changed in every page refresh.

How should I use `getElementById` to select this kind of tag name? I mean how should I bypass selecting the rest of the tag name?

Comment: An `id` attribute is usually a pretty good idea when working with `getElementById`.

Comment: @SebastianNette `id` attribute is random too.

Comment: Ah okay, then Pointy's answer should solve your problem.

Comment: [CSS2 Attribute Selectors with Regex](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/49368/css2-attribute-selectors-with-regex) ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well `.getElementById()` is off the table, because you're working with the "name" attribute of your `<iframe>` and not the "id".  You can (in sufficiently modern browsers) use `querySelector()` instead:

```
var frame = document.querySelector("[name^=tag_name_]");
```

The `^=` relation means, "starts with".

Looks like everything newer than IE8 should be OK with that.

Comment: Unless there can only be 1 iframe, then assignng an id and using `getElementById` is the better alternative. The name is not relevant in that case.

Comment: @SebastianNette Sure, if the element has an "id" then that works, but the OP would have the same problem if the "id" is also unpredictable. It's very common for people to ask questions like this about HTML markup over which they claim to have no control.

Comment: That's true. The question didn't give any information about that, but the OP commented a moment ago and confirmed that his id's are random too. So your answer should fit his needs.

Comment: perfect! It worked! actually `id` and `name` attributes have the same value .I did mistake

Answer (score 1):

First of all, that is not a *tag name* (the tag name here is `iframe`), and second of all, you should not (and *can* not) use `getElementById` to select an element by the content of its `name` attribute.

What you could and should use, is an attribute selector, more specifically one of the [Substring matching attribute selectors](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#attribute-substrings)

`document.querySelector` or `document.querySelectorAll` allow you to use such CSS selectors to select elements; and most frameworks have simple methods for selecting elements based on CSS selectors as well.